# High performing map of list

Tags: java, concurrency, concurrenthashmap

Suppose there exists a map of a key to a list.

```
ConcurrentMap<String,List<String>> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

Key is a batchId while value is a list of entries corresponding to the batch.
As entries are dispatched ,an insertion is made to the list.
On response,the entry is removed from the list. 
When no more entries exist corresponding to batchId - the entry is removed from the map.

Its a two step operation each time - finding the list corresponding to a batchID,followed by an insert/remove from the list.

Is there a better data structure/code path to make this entire operation 'lock-free' for a low latency environment?

Comment: lock-free in what sense? You know you are using a concurrent map which is the most locking thing you can choose!?

Comment: ConcurrentHashMap is divided into different segments based on concurrency level. So different threads can access different segments concurrently in java. What's the problem?

Comment: Map is concurrent - not the list

Comment: @luk2302, but it's not really. CHM only locks the hash bucket. It's possible to operate in "nowait" if there is no contention over one bucket in the map.

Comment: @IUnknown, unless you update list atomically, you would have consistency problem on your hands.

Comment: Could the List be a "ConcurrentSet"? (`Set<String> entries = Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<>())`)

Comment: Rather than rolling your own, would Guava's Multimaps work for you? I'm specifically thinking about MultiMaps.synchronizedMultimap -
 https://google.github.io/guava/releases/18.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#synchronizedMultimap(com.google.common.collect.Multimap)